# MariaDB Fails to log in error log

Tags: mariadb, logging

I am using MariaDB Version 5.5.56
The database was restarted 2 days ago but I am not seeing any log entries in the error log except an error importing from a dmp file. The data seems complete and all processes and transactions are occuring correclt just no error logging. Is there a way to turn this on? I have tried "flush error logs" command but still no log entries.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute this to see where the error log file is supposed to be written:

```
show global variables like 'log_error';
```

This can (sometimes) show a relative path, relative to the datadir.

From the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/error-log/#activating-the-error-log):

> The error log is active by default. The log-error=filename option determines where the output will be written. If no file name is specified, the log will be written to host-name.err. If no absolute path is specified, the file will be written to the data directory (determined by the value of the datadir system variable).
>
> On Unix systems, if the --log-error option is not used, the errors are written to stderr (usually, the command line).
>
> On Windows, if the --console option is specified, and --log-error is not used, the errors are written to the console. If --log-error is present, --console is ignored.

Additionally, for warning messages, the log_warnings variable need to be > 0. There are different warning levels, and the higher the value of log_warnings, the more kinds of warning messages are logged. For details, see the [documentation for the log_warnings variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#log_warnings).

To see you current setting, run:

```
show global variables like 'log_warnings';
```